# How to encode a Frequency Assignment Problem in Z3 as Max-SMT

Tags: logic, z3, solver, smt, z3py

I'm trying to encode the [Frequency Assignment Problem](http://www7.inra.fr/mia/T/schiex/Doc/rlfap.shtml) (more specifically, Instance 6) via Z3 in Python by using the information from the paper [On SAT Modulo Theories and Optimization
Problems](https://www.cs.upc.edu/%7Eoliveras/espai/papers/sat06.pdf), which I'll try to briefly describe.

The problem consists of assigning frequencies to pairs of radio links such that some constraints are met. Each frequency should be chosen from a finite set *Di* and the constraints are of the form:

```
|fi − fj| > k (soft, comes with a cost associated )

|fi - fj| = d (hard)

fi = pi (pre-assignment, hard)
```

The paper describes how the domains can be seen as a disjoint union of four sets:

```
{2 + 14m | 1 ≤ m ≤ 11}
{2 + 14m | 18 ≤ m ≤ 28}
{8 + 14km | 29 ≤ m ≤ 39}
{8 + 14m | 46 ≤ m ≤ 56}
```

And that we can express that *fi* is in *Di* with:

```
ti  → (1 ≤ mi ≤ 11   ∨ 18 ≤ mi ≤ 28)

¬ti → (29 ≤ mi ≤ 39  ∨ 46 ≤ mi ≤ 56)
```

where *ti* indicates whether *fi* is *2 modulo 14* or not, and *mi* represents *fi mod 14*.

As for the constraints, it will depend on *ti* and *tj*. They can be written as

```
| 2 + 14mi - 8 - 14mj | > k
```

when *(ti ∧ ¬tj)*, and after some manipulation we get:

```
(ti ∧ ¬tj ) → ( mi−mj ≥ floor((k+6)/14 + 1 ∨  mi−mj ≤ ceil((-k-6)/14) - 1)
```

I've managed to use this encoding with a SolverFor('QF_LIA') and
it does return *unsat*, since the instance is unfeasible.

What I haven't managed to do is encode it as a Max-SMT problem.

I tried using Optimize instead and adding the soft constraints with their weights, while just asserting the hard ones, but Z3 goes for hours without giving me an answer.

The paper talks about each turning weighted clause

```
(Ci, wi) into (Ci ∨ pi)
```

where *pi* is a fresh propositional variable, and then using:

```
pi → (ki = wi)         ¬pi → (ki = 0)
```

for the weights. But I haven't quite understood it yet.

***Question 1***

Does it mean that

```
 (ti ∧ ¬tj ) → ( mi−mj ≥ floor((k+6)/14 + 1 ∨  mi−mj ≤ ceil((-k-6)/14) - 1)
```

becomes

```
  ((ti ∧ ¬tj ) → ( mi−mj ≥ floor((k+6)/14 + 1 ∨  mi−mj ≤ ceil((-k-6)/14) - 1) ∨ pi)
```

?

***Question 2***

How should I encode it if I want to minimize the costs and see its value?
Thanks,

## Edit

After posting the question I spent some time hacking at it.
Managed to get it to work on another instance (SUBCELAR6/CELAR6-SUB0, which is a small sub-instance of Instance 6) but the cost found (574) is greater than the optimal (159) [found here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.14.8545&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

[Repo can be found here with the dataset](https://gitlab.com/neocastro/tcc) but the main part is:

```py
import mongoengine as me
from models import Graph
from z3 import *
from math import ceil, floor

me.connect(db='tcc')

instance = next(Graph.objects(name='scen06')) 

Vars = instance.var 
Doms = instance.dom
Ctrs = instance.ctr


weights = {
 1 : 1000,
 2 :  100,
 3 :   10,
 4 :    1
}


s = Optimize()

for ctr in Ctrs:

  ti = Bool('t_%d' % ctr.first_var)
  tj = Bool('t_%d' % ctr.second_var)
  mi = Int('m_%d'  % ctr.first_var)
  mj = Int('m_%d'  % ctr.second_var)
  k  = ctr.deviation

  # ti  → (1  ≤ mi ≤ 11 ∨ 18 ≤ mi ≤ 28)
  # ¬ti → (29 ≤ mi ≤ 39 ∨ 46 ≤ mi ≤ 56)

  # Encoding the domain of Fi
   
  s.add(Implies(ti,      Or( And(1  <= mi, mi <= 11),  And(18 <= mi, mi <= 28))))
  s.add(Implies(Not(ti), Or( And(29 <= mi, mi <= 39),  And(46 <= mi, mi <= 56))))
   
  # Encoding the domain of Fj
  s.add(Implies(tj     , Or(And(1  <= mj, mj <= 11), And(18 <= mj, mj <= 28))))
  s.add(Implies(Not(tj), Or(And(29 <= mj, mj <= 39), And(46 <= mj, mj <= 56))))

  if ctr.operator == '=':
    # (ti ∧ ¬tj )
    s.add(Implies(And(ti,Not(tj)), Or(mi - mj == floor((k+6)/14) + 1, mi - mj == ceil((-k+6)/14) -1 )))

    # (¬ti ∧ tj)
    s.add(Implies(And(Not(ti),tj), Or(mi - mj == math.floor((k-6)/14) + 1, mi - mj == ceil((-k-6)/14) -1 )))
       
    # (ti ∧ tj)
    s.add(Implies(And(ti,tj), Or(mi - mj == math.floor(k/14) + 1, mi - mj == ceil(-k/14) -1 )))

    # (¬ti ∧ ¬tj)
    s.add(Implies(And(Not(ti),Not(tj)),   Or(mi - mj == math.floor(k/14) + 1, mi - mj == ceil(-k/14) -1 )))



  # encoding the soft constraints
    if ctr.operator == '>':
       
        weight = costs[ctr.weight]

        # (ti ∧ ¬tj)
        s.add_soft(
            Implies(And(ti, Not(tj)), Or( mi - mj >= floor((k+6)/14) + 1,  mi - mj <= ceil((-k+6)/14) -1 )),
            weight
        )

        # (¬ti ∧ tj)
        s.add_soft(
            Implies( And(Not(ti), tj), Or( mi - mj >= floor((k-6)/14) + 1,   mi - mj <= ceil((-k-6)/14) - 1 )),              
            weight
        )

        # (ti ∧ tj)
        s.add_soft(
            Implies(And(ti,tj) ,    Or( mi - mj >= floor(k/14) + 1   ,      mi - mj <= ceil(-k/14) -1   )),
            weight
        )
 

        # (¬ti ∧ ¬tj)
        s.add_soft(
            Implies(And(Not(ti), Not(tj)), Or(mi - mj >= floor(k/14) + 1,    mi - mj <= ceil(-k/14) -1 ))
            , weight
        )
 
   

print(s.check())

m = s.model()
print([ m.evaluate(o) for o in s.objectives() ])
```

Comment: I suspect @PatrickTrentin will be able to give you a much better answer when he gets around to it. In the mean time, it would be useful to share your encoding in Z3py, especially if you can simplify it so it is minimal yet it demonstrates the "runs for hours" problem. Stack-overflow works the best when you have code-segments to share that people can run independently.

Comment: **1)** Don't use the `(Ci, wi) into (Ci ∨ pi)` transformation. Instead, use `s.add_soft(Ci, wi)`, that can be handled with more efficient MaxSMT algorithms **2)** The minimization of `SUM weight_i` is implicit with `z3` when you use `add_soft()` **3)** The incorrect optimum result may be the result of an issue with the manipulation of the constraints, hard for me to say without a proper background. Try writing the equation *"as-is"* and let `z3` do the manipulation. **4)** If you can provide an `smt2` formula I can take a closer look at it.

Comment: I got the s-expressions from the solver [here](https://gitlab.com/snippets/1909342), is this what you need?

Comment: Oh dear, I found the issue. When adding the soft clause for (ti ∧ tj) I accidently typed '==' instead of '>='. In the end it found a cost of 160!